# Same hdd (ssd) password not working on different laptop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, password-recovery, password-protection

I have a samsung ultrabook which is not working anymore. So i decided to use it's ssd on different laptop. Tried on two different laptop (lenovo g570, samsung r522) but password is not working and i can not open system. And i am pretty sure about the password. It's "Yildiz".

What to do ?

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "password", are you talking about a log in password or have you encrypted the drive with a password?

Comment: @JasonBristol question updated

Answer (score 1):

The password is set in BIOS and different BIOSs use different password algorithm's.  Putting the hard drive into another machine will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the bios lock on your new laptop. This may circumvent the lock and allow you to access the hard drive. Ultimately your in a bit of a tough spot. I strongly advise against setting a hard drive password via the bios. If this is for security reasons take a look at encrypting your hard drive. Bios locks do not encrypt your drive, but rather just set a password needed to access it. These passwords can be brute-forced (exhaustively). You also run the gambit of what has happened to you here. Manufacturer support for data recover off locked hard drives is minimal at best.

Refer to these article to get a better idea for alternatives:

http://www.wwpi.com/index.php?option=com_content&id=2669&Itemid=129
http://blogs.computerworld.com/the_down_side_of_hard_drive_passwords